# Costs of the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I do know this is kind of out of place to ask here, but I still could not find a better place to ask this basically.

My company wants to use the Facebook Graph API (or any other form of querying data from facebook) for a project, which might grow rather large, and we want to know specific information about the pricing.

There is not much information to be found online and asking Facebook is about impossible. If anyone has any insights about this topic i would be delighted to hear about it.

More specific questions:

1. Is it free to use for commercial use? Can i just query it from my app without facebook really expecting anything in return?
2. I read about a 5 Mio. MAU and/or 100 Mio. Requests per day Limit before the terms of use might change. What happens after these thresholds?

Comment: The Graph API is free to use, for all applicable use cases. Rate Limiting applies though, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting There is no way to “pay” or otherwise get those limits raised for normal 3rd party apps.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question.

Answer (score 3):

Answered By the Comment from @04FS:

> The Graph API is free to use, for all applicable use cases. Rate Limiting applies though, > developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting There is no way to “pay” or > otherwise get those limits raised for normal 3rd party apps.